# Google AdMob Ads SDK vs Prev SDK

Tags: iphone, admob, ads, ios-frameworks

I am using Admob from the past one year in different projects. And all of them are working fine with the previous libAdmob.a libraries.

As I can see [Google has launched new libraries](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/fundamentals.html) like GADBanner classes, libGoogleAdmobAds.a and all.

My concern is, if I will continue using with previous libraries, will it create any problem on Ads revenue?

Comment: can you please send me previous libraries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have delayed updating my applications for a while too, and it didn't cause any problem. Google wouldn't want to kill its own revenue by not serving ads to older applications.

I would recommend updating sooner or later, though, since the new libraries are required for new formats (iPad, etc.). Other than that, I haven't noticed a significant difference between revenue in recently updated applications and older ones. In both cases revenue has gone down due to, I believe, market conditions.

Comment: I would not recommend it. I'm having a world of trouble here. (So bad I had to post a question!)